# SIGSEGV when executing RDOTNET under mono

Tags: c#, mono, r.net

I keep getting a SIGSEGV when executing a .NET.Program under mono which wokrs perfectly fine when run on a Windows-maschine.

The error reads like that:

```
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0x2b32fe108a20 (intptr,intptr,bool&) <0xffffffff>
  at RDotNet.Expression.TryEvaluate (RDotNet.REnvironment,RDotNet.SymbolicExpression&) <0x00067>
  at RDotNet.REngine.Parse (string,System.Text.StringBuilder) <0x0026f>
  at RDotNet.REngine/<Defer>d__0.MoveNext () <0x00263>
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault<TSource_REF> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<TSource_REF>) <0x000d6>
  at RDotNet.REngine.Evaluate (string) <0x00037>
  at Strompreisprognose.Tools.SpotPriceForecast.SpotPriceForecastCalculator.Regressio
  [...]
  at SpotPriceForecast.Program.Main (string[]) <0x00173>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

        mono() [0x49cf0c]
        mono() [0x4f2d5e]
        mono() [0x4249dd]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf8d0) [0x2b32f49d48d0]
        [0x2b32f7e01284]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

What came to my mind is simply calling `Dispose()` on the used `REngine`s which is used in a loop since it seems to overflow in some way, but that is not possible, because the `REngine`-Singleton cannot be reinitialized onces it has been disposed by design.

Increasing the Maschines Memory or ulimit dit not help either. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Comment: it appears on both, `3.2.8` and `4.2.1`... :(

Answer (score 1):

Unless the RDotNet assembly is doing P/Invoke and has a bug in its integration with the platform, a SIGSEGV in mono is always a bug in the runtime, please report your bug here, attaching a minimal testcase:

http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: It appears to be a R-problem. Clearing the Workspace wherever possible seems to resolve the problem. We'll do some further inspection on this, and as soon as we have a min. reproduction well raise an issue as you supposed. Thx anyways.